# Как правильно использовать переменную базы данных?

Tags: python, база-данных, aiogram

Суть в чём, у меня есть отдельный файл с классом базы данных, где она создается и выполняет небольшой функционал.

```py
class Database():
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('models/{0}'.format(db_file))
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def get_random_name(self, name):
        list_names = self.cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM {0}'.format(name)).fetchall()
        self.conn.close()
        return random.choice(list_names)[0]
```

После чего я создаю переменную этой базы данных и подключаюсь к ней из главного файла проекта app.py. Но мне нужно использовать функционал базы данных ещё в нескольких отдельных модулях, как это правильно сделать? Открывать заново базу данных в новых модулях будет ли считаться правильным? Или просто импортировать переменную базы данных из app во все другие модули?
Как это сделать более правильно, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Просто импортируйте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Импортируйте класс в нужный модуль

создаете экземпляр класс

```
db = Database('db_file.db')
```

и вызываете метод db.get_random_name()
Главное не забудьте указать название файла базы данных и передать аргумент name

Comment: А что делать, если мне нужно вызывать этот метод в нескольких отдельных модулях? Будет ли правильным в каждом модуле снова импортировать, создавать экземпляр класса и вызывать метод? Мне интересна сама структура и насколько это будет правильно. Сейчас я так и сделал, в 3 модулях у меня импортируется класс Database, после чего создается экземпляр и вызывается метод. Опять же, не создаст ли это каких-то проблем?

Comment: Проблем никаких не будет, можете создать экземпляр в отдельном файле и импортировать его